# Search Engine Script - Undefined variables

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a small problem in my code and I can't figure out what is it..

I'm trying to make a sample search engine tool in PHP , everything works good until i've tryied to search some posts from database... When I do that , it says I don't have $header and $bio declared ...

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

$query =mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['query']);

$q = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id FROM search WHERE header LIKE '%$query%' OR bio LIKE '%$query%'");


$num = mysqli_num_rows($q);

echo $num;

if(!$query){
echo "Enter a query...";
} else {

if($num != 0)
{

    echo "<hr>";
    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){

       $id = $fetch['id'];
        $header = $fetch['header'];
        $bio = $fetch['bio'];


    echo "<strong>" . $header . "</strong>";
    echo "<blockquote><p>" . $bio . "</p></blockquote>";
    echo "<hr>";

    }

} else {
    echo "No results where found .. ";
}

}

?>
```

and the form

```
<div style = "width:300px; margin:auto;">

    <h1> Add Search Criteria</h1>
    <p> Type a header and bio below to add to search engine</p>

    <p>
        <input id="header" name = "header" type="text" placeholder="header" style="width:100%;">
    </p>

    <p>
        <textarea id="bio" name="bio" cols="40" rows="7" placeholder="Write a bio.."></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <center>
            <button id="submit">Submit Search</button>
        </center>
    </p>

    <div id="add_error" style="text-align:center"></div>

    <hr>

    <h1>Search The Database</h1>
    <p>Please type something to search to database</p>

    <p>
        <input name = "query" id="query" type="text" placeholder="search">
        <button id="search">Search</button>
    </p>

    <div id="search_error">

    </div>

</div>
```

this is what it outputs

Notice: Undefined index: header in C:\wamp64\www\mywebsite\Search\search.php on line 25
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0021  242472  {main}( )   ...\search.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: bio in C:\wamp64\www\mywebsite\Search\search.php on line 26
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0021  242472  {main}( )   ...\search.php:0

Comment: add header and bio columns in your select query.

Comment: Add both the `header` and `bio` to your query, like `SELECT id, header, bio FROM search WHERE header LIKE '%$query%' OR bio LIKE '%$query%'`.  But you really should use a prepared query to prevent attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add header and bio columns in your select query.

```
$q = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT id, header, bio FROM search WHERE header LIKE '%$query%' OR bio LIKE '%$query%'");
```

Comment: or ...selecting all SELECT * FROM ....Thank you for your idea , you opened my eyes

Comment: Please do not go for Select * option as you'll end up fetching all the columns from the table including the one you don't need.  Only add columns to the Select statement which you need to work on in your script.